# How to set number of test run(s) on TFS 2010 build?

Tags: msbuild, build

Is it possible to set number of test runs variable on TFS 2010 build so that is displayed in the build summary? We are running NUnit tests and can get the number of tests run. At the moment we see "No Test Results" in build summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and congratulations on your promotion from shoe-salesman to TFS technician... :)

You can add the NUnit test run results to the TFS build report in one of two ways:
1. You can write a simple XSLT to transform the nunit report to a TRX file (which TFS can read).
2. You can use [NUnit for Team Build](http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/releases/view/45765).

Either way, the NUnit results will be added to the report, including the count of successful, failed, inconclusive and (IIRC) total count of tests.

Hope this helps,
Assaf.